# Tensorflow: Variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Here is a part of my tensorflow RNN network code written in jupyter. The whole code runs perfect for the first time, however, running it furthermore produces an error. The code:

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

def recurrent_nn_model(x):
   x = tf.transpose(x, [1,0,2])
   x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, chunk_size])
   x = tf.split(x, n_chunks, 0)

   lstm_layer = {'hidden_state': tf.zeros([n_batches, lstm_size]),
              'current_state': tf.zeros([n_batches, lstm_size])}
   layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([lstm_size, n_classes])),
         'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}
   lstm = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
   rnn_outputs, rnn_states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm, x, dtype=tf.float32)
   output = tf.add(tf.matmul(rnn_outputs[-1], layer['weights']), 
            layer['biases'])

   return output
```

The error is:

> Variable rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did
>   you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

Answer (score 3):

If `recurrent_nn_model` is the whole network, just add this line to reset previously defined graph:

```py
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

If you're intentionally calling `recurrent_nn_model` several times and combine these RNNs into one graph, you should use different variable scopes for each one:

```py
 with tf.variable_scope('lstm1'):
   recurrent_nn_model(x1)
 with tf.variable_scope('lstm2'):
   recurrent_nn_model(x2)
```

Comment: I tried both methods you mentioned, and I got errors. following is the error I got using the first method:                                                              
ValueError: Input graph and Layer graph are not the same: Tensor("split:0", shape=(?, 28), dtype=float32) is not from the passed-in graph.

Comment: This means you're resetting the graph, but then not redefining some of the nodes. It all boils down to how your notebook is organized

Comment: putting tf.reset_default_graph() at the beginning of code works!